# MySQL won't allow login from normal user account

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

When connecting to MySQL as **root** from the linux user **user**

```
user@computer:~/$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

When doing the same exact same thing but as the linux uer **root** it works.

```
user@computer:~/$ sudo mysql -u root -p
sudo mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 19
Server version: 5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Before you mention, that MySQL was installed as '**root**' or that MySQL is running as the '**root**' user, it was installed with **apt-get** which per MySQL Docs means it will force and always run as '**mysql**' linux user account.

I have no idea why this is happening. I reinstalled MySQL completely from scratch, nope. Rebooted, same issue.

MySQL Service:

```
user@computer:~/$ service mysql status
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2016-06-27 13:56:42 CDT; 38min ago
  Process: 18007 ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 18001 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 18006 (mysqld)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─18006 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Jun 27 13:56:41 d4rkt0p systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Jun 27 13:56:42 d4rkt0p systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
```

Answer (score 0):

Per your post above, it appears that the reason the user isn't connecting the second time is due to it not receiving the correct password. Relevant:

> user@computer:~/$ mysql -u newuser -p
>   Enter password:
>   ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'newuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>   user@computer:~/$

You will need to figure out the reason that the new user is not using the password the second time, and also verify that the password is being used the second time.

Comment: Doug, correct. 2nd part resolved, thank you!

Comment: Still having issues connecting as non-root user... using same mysql root login.

Comment: Unfortunately with that issue I have not had too much experience. I do know that in the past I have followed the instructions at this post and they worked for me      http://askubuntu.com/questions/766334/cant-login-as-mysql-user-root-from-normal-user-account-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: After some time and troubleshooting the issue was with using 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1', also had issues with some MySQL security settings in more recent versions. I had to configure some stuff and restart mysql_server and it worked eventually. All I can say to others having issues is using an older version worked better. If you use newer vers, be sure to understand security configurations.